# Number of functions in set

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, summation

I'm studying for my discrete math midterm and having some trouble with this question:

A{1,2,3,...,n} and B={a,b,c}

A fixed integer k such that 0 =< k =< n and a fixed subset S of A having size k. How many functions f : A->B are there that:

1) For all x ∈ S, f(x) ∈ {a,b},

2) For all x ∈ A\S, f(x) = c

3) Show that the sum $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^n c(n,k) 2^k$ counts every functions f:A->B

To begin off I can see that there are $3^n$ functions for f:A->B, so I'm assuming for 1) it'll be $3^2$ since there are only 2 elements?

For 2, I'm thinking it will $3^1$ since c is the only element?

As for 3, I'm not sure where to even begin off. Any help would be appreciated.

Is my thinking correct or off completely?

Thanks.

Comment: Something got lost in copying the problem. What was *A fixed integer k such that 0=B are there that* supposed to say?

Comment: Yes something did get lost:

A fixed integer k with 0<=k<=n and a fixed subset S of A that has size of k.
How many functions f : A -> B are there that...

Comment: Ah, good; that’s what I suspected, and that’s how I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I’m going to make an educated guess that in $(1)$ and $(2)$ we’re actually supposed to have a set $S\subseteq A$ such that $|S|=k$, and we’re trying to count the functions $f:A\to B$ such that $f(x)\in\{a,b\}$ for each $x\in S$, **and** $f(x)=c$ for each $x\in A\setminus S$. If that’s the case, $(1)$ and $(2)$ aren’t separate questions. In any case your answers don’t take the set $S$ into account and appear to be based on a fundamental misunderstanding.

The reason that there are $3^n$ functions from $A$ to $B$ is that for each $x\in A$ you have $3$ choices for $f(x)$, and there are $n$ elements of $A$, so you’re making a $3$-way choice $n$ times in a row. By the [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) there are $$\underbrace{3\cdot3\cdot\ldots\cdot3}_{n\text{ factors}}=3^n$$ ways to do this. If we count only those functions from $A$ to $B$ that map every element of $A$ to $a$ or $b$, then we’re making $n$ $2$-way choices; this can be done in $2^n$ ways. (It should be clear that $3^2$ can’t be right, because it doesn’t depend on $n$.) And if we look at functions from $S$ to $\{a,b\}$, we’re making $k$ $2$-way choices, something that can be done in $2^k$ ways. Thus, there are $2^k$ functions from $S$ to $\{a,b\}$. This implies that there are $2^k$ functions from $A$ to $B$ such that $f(x)\in\{a,b\}$ for each $x\in S$, and $f(x)=c$ for each $x\in A\setminus S$; why? Call this set of $2^k$ functions $\mathscr{F}(S)$.

For the last part of the question, let $f:A\to B$ be any function, and let $$S_f=\big\{x\in A:f(x)\in\{a,b\}\big\}\;;$$ then $f$ is one of the $2^k$ functions in $\mathscr{F}(S_f)$. Every function from $A$ to $B$ is in exactly one of the sets $\mathscr{F}(S)$ as $S$ runs over all possible subsets of $A$.

- For $k=0,1,\ldots,n$, how many subsets of cardinality $k$ does $A$ have?
- If $S$ is a subset of $A$ of cardinality $k$, how many functions are in $\mathscr{F}(S)$?

Answer those two questions correctly, and put the answers together correctly, and you’ll have an answer to the last question.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, I'm still kind of confused for x∈A∖S, f(x)=c. What does c mean? Is it only one element? Also does A\S mean A or S?

Also, for the 2 questions you gave to me, will it be 2 (since elements a and b are in the set) and 1 (since 1 subset exists in A and S is subset of A), respectively. Is this correct?

Comment: @pyramid: Yes, $c$ is the other element of $B$ besides the ones in $\{a,b\}$. $A\setminus S$ is the set difference: it’s the set of things that are in $A$ but not in $S$. An old-fashioned notation that you still sometimes see is $A-S$. As for the questions, $a$ and $b$ have nothing to do with the first question: it’s about subsets of $A$, and $a$ and $b$ are elements of $B$. $A$ is an $n$-element set; how many $k$-element subsets does it have? HINT: Binomial coefficients. In the second question you have to combine information on the number of functions from ...

Comment: ... $S$ to $\{a,b\}$ and the number of functions from $A\setminus S$ to $\{c\}$ to get the number of functions in $\mathscr{F}(S)$.